# How to convert a column with multiple values into a single row with many columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

My excel file has 213,262 records - approximately 43k claims.  There are multiple CPT codes for each claim listed in a single column.  I need to convert each claim to 1 row with multiple columns, a column for each CPT code.  The number of codes vary for each claim but I only want to see a max of 30 CPT codes.
Right now, my data looks like this:

```
Item #    CPT
123456789 11111
123456789 22222
123456789 33333
123456789 44444
```

I need it to be:

```
Item #    CPT1  CPT2  CPT3  CPT4  
123456789 11111 22222 33333 44444
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO, approaching a quarter million records, you want a database, not a spreadsheet. Then this type of data presentation would be [relatively] easy.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What type of solution are you looking for? One answer already suggests a VBA script. For formula based with excel web/365 use `TAKE` with a combination of other formulas (possibly `OFFSET` for older versions of excel). If you add a helper column (probably using `COUNTIF`) to enumerate CPT per Item # then a Pivot table would also work. With over 200K rows, I can't tell you anything about speed of these potential solutions. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is not as difficult a task as it might seem at first glance.

There are several different approaches to the solution. For example, as already mentioned in the comment (and I completely agree with this opinion), you can transfer the table data to the database and convert it to the required form using the SQL instruction.

Since your data is already in the Excel worksheet, you can use the built-in Excel mechanisms. For example, using the `UNIQUE()` functions, build a list of all **Items** and using `TRANSPOSE(FILTER())` get the **CPT** values for each of them.

Or you can use a not very complicated VBA code: just collect all the available **Items** keys in the `Dictionary` and create a **CPT** `Collection` for each of them. After this, convert the accumulated data into a rectangular two-dimensional array. The code could be like this:

```
Function getPivot(aData As Range, nCountCRT As Long) As Variant
Dim aAllItems As Object
Dim aCRTs As Collection
Dim aRow As Range
Dim sItem As Variant, sCRT As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim aResult() As Variant
Rem Collect data from range aData:
    Set aAllItems = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each aRow In aData.Rows
        sItem = aRow.Cells(1).Value
        sCRT = aRow.Cells(2).Value
        If aAllItems.Exists(sItem) Then
            Set aCRTs = aAllItems(sItem)
            aCRTs.Add sCRT
            Set aAllItems(sItem) = aCRTs
        Else
            Set aCRTs = New Collection
            aCRTs.Add sCRT
            aAllItems.Add sItem, aCRTs
        End If
    Next aRow
Rem Repack data to array:
    ReDim aResult(1 To aAllItems.Count, 0 To nCountCRT)
    i = 0
    For Each sItem In aAllItems.keys
        i = i + 1
        aResult(i, 0) = sItem
        j = 0
        For Each sCRT In aAllItems(sItem)
            j = j + 1
            If j > nCountCRT Then Exit For
            aResult(i, j) = sCRT
        Next sCRT
    Next sItem
Rem Set first row as Table Header
    For i = nCountCRT To 1 Step -1
        aResult(1, i) = aResult(1, 1) & i
    Next i
    getPivot = aResult
End Function
```

With this function you can easily get a new sheet in your book with the desired result. Let's assume that all your data is on the active sheet and starts from the first cell of the first row, cell A1. Then this procedure will do the job:

```
Sub createPivot()
Dim a As Variant
Dim sheet As Worksheet
    a = getPivot(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(, 2), 30)
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    sheet.Range(Cells(1), Cells(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2) + 1)).Value = a
End Sub
```

Another way to solve your problem that should be mentioned is to use the PowerQuery tool, which is located on the Data tab. This tool is designed specifically for data conversion tasks. To master it, you will need to watch several videos [**on YouTube**](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=power+query), read the description of functions in the [**Language M**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m) reference book, and look for recommendations on using the tool on the forums.

Once you have the right skills, you can solve problems like these with a few clicks.

Convert your source data into a table named something like `SourceTable` (**Ctrl+T**).

Select the "From Table" command on the Data tab, click the necessary buttons on the toolbars and get code like this

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceTable"]}[Content],
    SetCPTtypeAsText = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"CPT", type text}}),
    GroupItems = Table.Group(SetCPTtypeAsText, {"Item #"}, {{"GroupByItems", each _, type table}}),
    ConvertGroupToString = Table.AddColumn(GroupItems, "CPT", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(List.Distinct(Table.Column([GroupByItems], "CPT")),30), "#(tab)")),
    SplitStringToColumns = Table.SplitColumn(ConvertGroupToString,"CPT",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(tab)"),{"CPT.1", "CPT.2", "CPT.3", "CPT.4", "CPT.5", "CPT.6", "CPT.7", "CPT.8", "CPT.9", "CPT.10", "CPT.11", "CPT.12", "CPT.13", "CPT.14", "CPT.15", "CPT.16", "CPT.17", "CPT.18", "CPT.19", "CPT.20", "CPT.21", "CPT.22", "CPT.23", "CPT.24", "CPT.25", "CPT.26", "CPT.27", "CPT.28", "CPT.29", "CPT.30"}),
    RemoveTemporaryColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(SplitStringToColumns,{"GroupByItems"})
in
    RemoveTemporaryColumn
```

This script is slightly shorter than the VBA macro above and runs a second or two faster, but produces the same result. But creating such a scenario requires certain skills

Hope this was helpful